# Rethinkdb cluster on different Google Compute Engine VMs

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, rethinkdb

I am trying to create a Rethinkdb cluster from multiple VMs on Google Compute Engine. Rethink docs say to do  this for first machine:

```
$ rethinkdb --bind all
```

And then on the seconds machine to do this:

```
$ rethinkdb --join IP_OF_FIRST_MACHINE:29015 --bind all
```

I did this and it seems to work and returns this:

```
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
```

But, my admin panel does not show another server connected.

I am pretty new to rethink, but any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you opened up your port 29015 in the firewall?

Comment: I had not. Thanks, I knew it was something stupid, however now i get this:
`error: Received inconsistent routing information (wrong address) from ip-address:29015 , closing connection.  Consider using the '--canonical-address' launch option.`

Comment: https://rethinkdb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#how-do-i-specify-an-external-canonical-ip-address-of-a-rethinkdb-node

Comment: ok. I added `canonical-address` and i no longer get that error, but i went back to the separate machine and ran this command:
`rethinkdb --join IP_ADDRESS:29015 --bind all`
and it says:
`Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015`
But the web admin still does not detect it

Comment: Telnet in to the machine to see if the port is accessible. `telnet IP_ADDRESS 29015`

Comment: Got this:
`telnet: connect to address IP_ADDRESS: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`
But i did enable tcp:29015 on google cloud

Comment: I'm not familiar with google cloud much - best read up on some firewall documentation.